# iOS reply to email with attachment

Tags: iphone, ios, email

Is there a way to attach an image from the library using the default Mail app, while replying to an email?

‘Email photo’ in the Camera roll creates a new message, and ‘Reply’ doesn't give you an option to attach, as far as I can tell. I would also like to have the ability to attach multiple images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to add a photo as an attachment is to open you photo library while multi-tasking find the photo you want to attach.

Hold down on the image until the copy button appears, Hit copy.

Go back to Mail and hold down in the body of the message. Hit paste when the option shows up.

Repeat until you have all the attachments you wanted.

Comment: Man, wish I had asked this a long time ago, instead of assuming it wasn't possible..

Comment: it's not as obvious as it could be really. There are a lot of things that stump me on Mac and then I learn a short cut. Every time this happens my life is made that tiny bit easier. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Its also possible to attach multiple photos at once. To do so (applies to iOS 8.1.1):

1. Switch to the "Photos" app and tap "Select" button in the upper
   right corner
2. Select photos you wish to attach
3. Tap "Share" button in the left bottom corner (box with an arrow pointing outwards) and choose "Copy"
4. Switch to the "Mail" app, click "Reply" and hold in the body of the message until the pop-up menu appears.
5. Choose "Paste"